# Android : Capture current frame from streaming video

Tags: android, video-streaming, media-player, video-capture, textureview

I made a video player by TextureView and Mediaplayer. And I want to capture current frame. I found some questions about this. But They deal with capturing video from local video file. But I need capturing current video frame from streaming video. How can i do this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're sending data to a TextureView, just call `getBitmap()` - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html#getBitmap() .

Comment: @fadden Thanks for your answer! It works fine. And I found something. If call the getBitmap() in onSurfaceTextureDestroyed() callback, it returns always the same bitmap.